# What is the proper way to fully cover a sphere with tiny objects so they look cluttered?

Tags: materials, instances

I'm new in Blender. I'm trying to design a 3D model of a virus that reminds the COVID-19. I want have a surface which has these "seeds" growing out of it. Best way to this seems to be instancing. But the final results looks like a material that is more fit for teddy bear or something. I include a picture of what i've done. Please tell me the proper way to do this.

[image]

Comment: Particle system, maybe.

Comment: do you have a picture of the virus you're trying to model? It would help to find the solution

Comment: What means "2. Turned on instancing for sphere on faces"? That isn't the hair particle system, is it?

Comment: It depends on the specific look you want. instancing is not always great, because what it does is placing one sphere on eahc vertex/face of the mesh, so it's very geometric and hard to modify. Best thing is a particles system in "Hair" mode, so you can spread the spheres around more randomly so it's less "teddy beary", and it's less mesh dependent, which is always good.